# Alternative to multiple while(true) condition in same class in c#

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I am working with one application(C# Service), where I need some functionalities like below

```
Main()
    {
        App.A();
        App.B();    
    }
App
    {
        static A()
        {
            While(true)
            {
                // Thread logic comes here
                Thread.Sleep(60000)
            }
        }

        static B()
        {
            While(true)
            {
                // Thread logic comes here
                Thread.Sleep(1000)
            }
        }
    }
```

1. I need to execute 2 different thread logics in one class
2. Both is required with different sleep time

How to keep running both the functionalities in this case ? Suggest me any alternative to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Are you asking how to start `A` and `B` in separate threads?

Comment: Actually If I made A() and B() as a thread, it will be multiple thread logic and thought to start threads from A & B. I have multi-thread logic in Both A and B. This will difficult to handle so I found this to be preferable. But stuck in this particular implementation

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Tell us the details of what A and B are.

Answer (score 1):

You either need a *Threads* / *Tasks* or use some sort of *Timer*. There are many ways to do this but you really need to understand what you want to do.

However these might give you food for thought

**Disclaimer**, You should research these approaches especially tasks, before you attempt this.

**Option 1**

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        // do the work in the loop
        await Task.Delay(60000);
    }
});
```

**Option 2**

```
DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();

void DoWorkTimer()
{
    _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
    _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
    _timer.IsEnabled = true;
}

void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do the work in the loop
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this